# Date Time format in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

I have a function that needs parameter with type `Date Time`. For now, I'm using this.

```
DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 5));
```

It means when the date and time in my app `==` `DateTime.now()` with delayed 5 seconds. It's will execute some function. But in my case, I need a specific date and time. For example, when date and time in my app `==` `2020-08-30(for the date will dynamically by day) 21:00:00`, it will execute some function. And the question is, how to make `Date Time` to a specific like `21:00:00`, so my function will execute every day with time is `21:00:00`?

Comment: do you want to execute some function 5 seconds after pressing a button or an event else happen? 
for that you can use a Future function with 5 seconds delay

Comment: I think the main question is " how to make Date Time format". I just post how to format custom String using intl package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

1. Use Intl Package
2. Use Customized DateFormat

[image: Screenshot]

### Full Working Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: AddedTime(),
    );
  }
}

class AddedTime extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final timeFormat = new DateFormat('h:m:s a');

    final timeInString = "09:00:00 PM";

    var datetimeObject = timeFormat.parseStrict(timeInString);
    var newDatetimeObject = datetimeObject.add(Duration(seconds: 5));

    final now = DateTime.now();
    final dateFormat = new DateFormat('y/M/d');
    final completeFormat = new DateFormat('y/M/d h:m:s a');
    final todayInString = dateFormat.format(now);
    final completeString = "$todayInString $timeInString";

    var completeDatetimeObject = completeFormat.parseStrict(completeString);
    var newCompleteDatetimeObject = completeDatetimeObject.add(Duration(seconds: 5));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "$timeInString",
            ),
            Text(
              "${datetimeObject.toString()}",
            ),
            Text(
              "${newDatetimeObject.toString()}",
            ),
            Text(
              "${completeDatetimeObject.toString()}",
            ),
            Text(
              "${newCompleteDatetimeObject.toString()}",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Step by step Tutorial

#### 1. Install Dependencies

Add to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.16.1               <---------- Add this
```

Run in your terminal

```
flutter pub get
```

#### 2. Import Intl Package

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

#### 3. Create Date Format and use `parseStrict`

```dart
    final timeFormat = new DateFormat('h:m:s a');
    
    final timeInString = "09:00:00 PM";

    var datetimeObject = timeFormat.parseStrict(timeInString);
    var newDatetimeObject = datetimeObject.add(Duration(seconds: 5));
```

#### 4. [Optional] If you need more precise date

we can utilize DateTime.now() function

```dart
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final dateFormat = new DateFormat('y/M/d');
    final completeFormat = new DateFormat('y/M/d h:m:s a');
    final todayInString = dateFormat.format(now);
    final completeString = "$todayInString $timeInString";

    var completeDatetimeObject = completeFormat.parseStrict(completeString);
    var newCompleteDatetimeObject = completeDatetimeObject.add(Duration(seconds: 5));
```

Comment: Why the date is `1970-01-01`? not this day (I want dynamic, for example, today is2020-08-30, and tomorrow is 2020-08-31, etc)?

Comment: Because - '1st January 1970' usually called as "epoch date" is the date when the time started for Unix computers. Therefore, You need to provide date, not just 09.00.00 pm like you asked before

Comment: I've added new way to add precise date

Comment: Sorry about that, I already update my question to more clear. So I still need `intl` package to handle my case?

Comment: Sure, intl package will provide us DateFormat class

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `Future` instead

```
if(DateTime.now()==theTime){
             Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((value) => {
                 //Do excuse the function
               });
              }
```

Comment: Please read carefully my question, my question is how to execute some function when the `Date Time` is `09:00:00 PM` and also add delay `5 seconds`

Comment: Please be specific to your question.